# Python Dictionary - Yaml File Empty Line

Tags: python, dictionary, kubernetes, yaml

I have yaml file which I created from my dictionary. The format looks good but I want to add one line space between some keys that are kubernetes resources like:service, deployment, secret etc. How can I do that with python? Is there a way to work on this with python dicitonary or yaml files? This is what I have:

```
   hpa:
    projectName:
      maxReplicas: 6
      minReplicas: 2
      targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 250
  secret:
    projectName:
      name: projectName-secret
  service:
    projectName:
      name: projectName-service
      selector:
        app: projectName
```

This is what I want:

```
      hpa:
        projectName:
          maxReplicas: 6
          minReplicas: 2
          targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 250

      secret:
        projectName:
          name: projectName-secret

      service:
        projectName:
          name: projectName-service
          selector:
            app: projectName
```

Comment: Nothing trivial, I'm afraid. You'd have to write your own serializer which adds an empty line after every value, but uses the default serializer for nested dicts. At the very least, you'll need to specify what you are using to generate the YAML file, because there the standard library doesn't support YAML.

Comment: What you have is not a valid YAML file. You cannot start with the first line indented 3 spaces and then have lines indented only two spaces. If that is an error on your side please correct it, and explain why all of the content of the file is indented in the first place and why you want the output to be even further indented.

Answer (score 0):

just go by-lines and add what you want between 'em

*untested

```py
block_headers = ["hpa", "secret", "service"]
indent   = None  # cause an Exception if used for slicing outside block
in_block = None  # secret ternary
block_start = False
with open(path_src) as fh_src, open(path_dest, "w") as fh_dest:
    for line in fh_src:
        # see if we've entered a block
        for header in block_headers:
            position = line.find(f"{header}:")
            if position >= 0:  # -1 for didn't find
                block_start = True
                in_block    = True
                indent = position
                break  # no need to check other headers

        # test if still in a block
        if block_start or (in_block is True and line[:indent].startswith(" ")):
            fh_dest.write(line)
            block_start = False
            continue  # go to next line

        # exited block
        indent   = None
        in_block = False
        block_start = False  # can this be True?

        # writing destination file
        fh_dest.write("\n")  # add that newline
        fh_dest.write(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's a dumb idea, but why not open the file after it has been written, search for all lines that don't start with whitespace, and prepend a line break?

Comment: Since all lines start with white space in the example the OP gives, that would not solve the problem.

Comment: The shown example does not contain any parent keys and - as you have commented yourself - the indentation is not consistent. Can we agree, that one could search for lines with a specific indentation level?

Comment: I agree you can search for lines at a certain indention level, but that is not what you propose. And you should not process lines in arbitrary YAML by just looking at the indentation of a line. You have to deal with comments (relatively easy), and some parsers allow multi-line scalars to be dedented (IMO they shouldn't but the specs are arguably not 100% clear). There are multi-document YAML files for which the data representation changes when you insert newlines before the (non-indented)

Comment: end-of-document marker.  And then there are documents with a single literal scalar, where you better not insert additional.